# REST Jackson Data Binding Conflicted Fileds

Tags: java, rest, jackson

I am attempting to use jackson binding in rest to bind bean object to json and  vice versa.
My bean has over 10 thousands of fields with nested bean and list of beans.
When jackson binding i got below exception.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting String creators: already had explicitly marked 
[constructor for java.lang.StringBuilder, annotations: [null]], encountered [constructor for java.lang.StringBuilder, annotations: [null]]
```

In jaxb, it will throws conflicted properties implicitly. But how to get conflicted fields when using jackson.

Comment: would be helpful, if you can post code of your domain obj

Comment: @ Jaydeep. domain obj have thousands of lines. i found that duplicate property. it was private String postalCode & private String Postal Code. but it was very difficult to find this duplicate property from thousands of property from bean.